# How to lose trusted context from click event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to create a userscript that causes the native popup blocker to apply to all popups, even those that were the result of user interaction.

I came up with the following idea:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.isTrusted);
  if (e.isTrusted) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.dispatchEvent(new e.constructor(e.type, e));
  }
}, true);

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  window.open('about:blank');
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Test</button>
```

(In the snippet window.open won't work because of the iframe sandbox.)

Basically the idea is to add an event listener to the page that replaces any click event that is trusted with a copy of it that isn't trusted. However this doesn't work and the popup is still opened.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Relevant specification here:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This just answers the *X* part of this *XY problem*, because I see no real use for the *Y*.</sup>

If you wish to block all popups, then `window.open = null;` will already block all the ones made from this method, then you may also want to block the ones from anchor elements,

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName === 'A' && e.target.target === "_blank") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Now, you'll have to apply this in all the documents (i.e in iframes too) and you should be good.

But note that there are many legit reasons for pages to open popup windows, and disabling it will definitely break a lot of websites.

Comment: Yeah that's why I want to apply the native popup blocker to all popups. That way you get a message when a popup is blocked and you can choose on which sites you want to allow them.

Comment: Just in case you didn't realize: the native popup blocker applies to all popups except those that are created as a result of a click event with isTrusted true. That's why I want to somehow replace the trusted event with an untrusted one, so the native popup blocker will apply to those popups as well.

Comment: @Bob hat you say is not true for every browser, each user has their own settings regarding this. Now, you said you wanted to build an extension that would  block all popups, the code I gave will do it. If you wish to add more, change the functions so that they do more.

Comment: I don't think you can fool the native blocker, which has the access to isTrusted long before it descends into the JS land.

Comment: @wOxxOm nobody wants to fool it here, what they want is to be even more strict than the native popup-blocker.

Comment: I've used a distracting word but the point is still valid: the native blocker won't even notice these struggles in the JS land. In other words I agree with your answer that the solution here is only to circumvent/prevent popups manually.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-blocker's handling of event contexts seems to be complex. Even generating a `setTimeout` with an evaluated string does not break the context. In Firefox there is a period of one second after a click to perform a popup, later it is cosidered not to be triggered by a click.

However, I could get Firefox to block popups using `setInterval`. I did not test it yet in Chrome.

We overwrite the `window.open` method with a custom one:

```js
      window.open = (function()
      {
        const
          openArgs  = [],
          fnOpen    = window.open.bind(window)
        ;

        setInterval( () => { for(let args; args = openArgs.pop(); fnOpen(args)); }, 100);

        return function open(...args) { openArgs.push(args); }  
      })();
```

```html
<button onclick="window.open('http://example.com');">button</button>
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.example.com');">open</a>
```